# variable 'product_id' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, sql, variables, flask-sqlalchemy

## route to make favorites of my project, serves to not duplicate when favorit, and check if it is #favored, I am also having difficulty to delete it

```
favoritar = request.form.getlist("produto")

print('produto', favoritar)
print('REQUEST FORM', request.form) 
favorito = Favoritos.query.filter_by(usuarios_id=current_user.id).all()

for id_prod in favoritar:
        if len(favorito) == 0: # verifica quantos favoritos está marcado no banco
            id_cliente = current_user.id
            novo_favorito = Favoritos(produtos_id=id_produto,usuarios_id=id_cliente)
            print('p',id_produto)
            print('c',id_cliente)
            db.session.add(novo_favorito)
        else:
            for fav in favorito:
                print('fav',fav)
                if len(fav) == 1:
                    pass



            print('primeiro',id_prod)
        for id_produto in favorito:
            print('segundo',id_produto.produtos_id)
            if id_prod != id_produto.produtos_id:
                id_cliente = current_user.id
                novo_favorito = Favoritos(produtos_id=id_produto,usuarios_id=id_cliente)
                print('p',id_produto)
                print('c',id_cliente)
                db.session.add(novo_favorito)
```

Comment: I don't see a variable "product_id" in the code snippet. Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume `id_produto` is the variable defined in your question title as `product_id`.

Please, could you edit your question to be sure you make consistent the error you are describing with the variables defined in the code you shared?

Anyway, making the assumption that `id_produto` is the `product_id`, if you check the next line in your code:

`novo_favorito = Favoritos(produtos_id=id_produto, usuarios_id=id_cliente)`

As you can see, you are assigning `productos_id=id_produto`, but, `id_produto` has not been declared before. So, that's the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

> I am working with python and the code above is from my post route, which is meant to deal with the favorites of a shopping schedule. The route variables are all of those I already mentioned in the code. As a student, I made with my teacher a new method of saving bookmarks to the database, below it is (sorry, I'm new to the area):

```
@app.route('/favoritar2', methods=['POST'])
def post_fav():
favoritar = request.form.getlist("produto")
try:    
    favorito = Favoritos.query.filter_by(usuarios_id=current_user.id).all()
    print('Favoritar', favoritar)
    print('REQUEST FORM', request.form)
    print('Favorito',favorito)

    for i in favoritar:
        fav2 = int(favoritar[i])
        print('FAV2',fav2)
        print('I-FAVORITAR',i)
        print('TYPE-FAVORITAR',type(i))
        print('FAVORITAR',favoritar)
        if i not in favorito:
            print('TYPE-FAVORITO',type(i))
            print('I-FAVORITO',i)
            print('FAVORITO',favorito)
            novo_favorito = Favoritos(produtos_id=i,usuarios_id=current_user.id)
            print("novo favorito", novo_favorito)
            db.session.add(novo_favorito)
            novo_favorito = ""
        else:
            print("Esse ja existe ",i)
    db.session.commit()
db.session.commit()

    flash('Favoritado!','success')
    print('ok')
except Exception as e:
    flash('Erro'+str(e),'danger')
    print('Erro '+str(e))

return redirect('/favoritar')
```